# Question is on topic here but may be better fit on bicycles.stackexchange.com

Tags: discussion, moderation, migration

My flag was declined here: [How to encourage a toddler to take interest in riding a balance bike?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/24120/2221)

This may be on topic here, but it has not received many positive comments and answers.

I wish to see more positive answers to this hence I request it to be moved to the bicycles.stackexchange.com where people recommend these bikes.

This question may get more exposure there.

Please move it.

Comment: The question is about how to encourage a child, which is perfectly on topic here.  Since it is on topic here (and I'm not sure how on topic it is over there) why should it be moved?  If it was your question, you might be given a little more sway over getting it moved.  Since it isn't, I don't really see much compelling evidence to justify a move.

Comment: I can see asking to have your own question moved to another site where it might receive more exposure, if it is on topic for both, but asking to move another person's question?  Not appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Migration is intended to happen when a question is off topic for the site on which it was first asked, but it could be salvaged by being posted on a different site. **Encouraging a child in an activity is completely on topic for parenting.** Just because you believe to could get better answers elsewhere (which, incidentally, is a gamble) is not a reason to migrate; that's true whether it is your question or another user's question.

1. As of today, four answers provide a variety of advice, and none had downvotes. One is fairly comprehensive and provides numerous sugestions to encourage a child. (While I believe there may have been only three when you posted your meta question, that is still a number that indicates a substantial amount of attention, interest, and capacity to answer in our own community.)
2. You mention "*postive* comments" -- I did delete one which was barely on-topic and largely talked about avoiding bikes entirely, which isn't very encouraging. I also commented on one answer which said little more than balance bikes aren't useful. **Note that a better approach if there are tone or content problems is to flag individual answers or comments for moderator attention, not migrate the question.** If you'd flagged content, a moderator could have helped with that much earlier.
3. Since it isn't your question, you can ask your own version on Bicycles instead. (Indeed, you're already an active user over there, so that is even easier.) A link back to this original question which inspired your interest in the topic will help them to understand the background, and you should also be specific about what you feel is lacking in the current version.
4. Posting a bounty is a great way to help attract more interest. Quality and variety of answers benefit you, the OP, the Parenting site in general, and anybody in future who does a Google search for encouraging a toddler to ride a balance bike.

I don't disagree with the decision to decline migration and would have done the same myself had I handled the flag. There are many ways to deal with what you perceive as inadequate response from the community that leave the question where it is.

Comment: If TheIndependentAquarius follows this advice, an edit to the Parenting question with a forward-link to the Bicycles question would be a good idea too.